# React-select auto loading options

Tags: reactjs, react-router

This if my first question on SO so hopefully I dont forget anything.

I am currently developing a site with React that allows the customer to type in the first few letters of a vehicle name and it searches the database bringing back results.  I am also accessing this site directly from another site via react-router and an iframe.

When I am coming in from the external site, I will be passing a query to react-router.  The query will come in something like:

> http://localhost:9292/#/?id=362789&start=1446015600000&stop=1446101999999

I would like react-select to automatically getOptions if "id" was included in the query.  Otherwise I would like it to continue to wait for user input as it is working now.

My current code looks something like.  I know I will need a if/else statement but more concerned with the auto-loading factor for now:

```
render() {
  const asset_id = this.props.id
  const getOptions = (input) => {
        return fetch(`/subject?q=${input}`, {credentials: 'include'})
        .then((response) => {
        return response.json();
        }).then((data) => {return {options: data}});
}    

return (
  <div className="picker">
    <Select.Async
        loadOptions={getOptions}
        minimumInput={2}
        value={this.state.selectValue}
        onChange={this.updateValue.bind(this)}
        ref="dropdown"
        name="chooser"
    />
  </div>
}
```

Any help you could give would be wonderful.  Im still getting familiar with React and I feel I am overlooking something simple possibly.

Comment: so add a componentDidMount() function that you check to see if you have an id in the params. if thats the case then call `this.getOptions`